# Does "VS Code Server" permit adding the GitHub CoPilot extension, as I only see it available in Visual Studio Code "client"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot, vscode-server

I'd like to add the GitHub CoPilot extension to my "Visual Studio Code Server", but it does not seem to be allowed of found when I search in the extensions search box.

However, If I search in the extensions search box for GitHub CoPilot on a separate client version of Visual Studio Code it's available.

Is that by design?

Will there be a version of GitHub CoPilot for "Visual Studio Code Server"?

Using my laptop's Google Chrome browser, I connected to "Visual Studio Code Server" I have installed on my AWS EC2 VM.  I then navigated to the Extensions icon within Visual Studio Code displaying within my browser and searched for GitHub CoPilot, hoping to add it as an available plugin. It does not show up in the list of available extensions. Is that by design? will there be a version available soon?

Comment: can you download the extension's VSIX and then install it on the remote machine with `code--install-extension`?